# Finding likelihood: Bayes Theorem (Follow Up)

Tags: self-study, bayesian

I've recently asked this question (two days ago). I'm still a bit unsure on some parts and I need help clarifying some points.

Previous question: [Finding likelihood: Bayes Theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/335752/finding-likelihood-bayes-theorem?noredirect=1#comment634678_335752)

I'm unsure on what exactly this part of the answer given by the user meant:

P(X = 4|H0) = .5^4(1-.5)^0

I understand only a part of the answer: .**5^4** -The data given the Null hypothesis is equal to the prior to the power of the data.

What I don't understand is where the value **1** or **0** , which is getting subtracted by **0.5** came from?

Any help is welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your experiment ($X$ = # of heads) follows a Binomial distribution. Now consider the pmf of a Binomial distribution:

$$P(X=k) = {n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

In this case, $X \sim \text{Bin}(4,p)$ given the null hypothesis. So $p=0.5$, $n=4$ and $k=4$. We get:

$$P(X=4|h_0) = {4 \choose 4}0.5^4(1-0.5)^{4-4}$$

Comment: Does the 'n' and 'k' here represent: n = number of tests, k = number of times it landed on heads?

Comment: N is number if observations (flips) and k is number of successes (heads)